# Creating a Query on Java using an FK as filter

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jpql

I have a class called `Curso` and a class called `Disciplina`.

`Disciplina` has a **FK** from `Curso` called `id_curso`. I want to filter `Disciplina`'s using `Curso`'s ID as a fitler.

```
public List<Disciplina> listarDisciplinaPorCurso(Long curso) {
    String jpql = "select u from Disciplina u where u.curso =:id_curso";
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ProjetoIntegradorPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    List<Disciplina> resultado = em.createQuery(jpql, Disciplina.class).setParameter("id_curso", curso).getResultList();
    if (resultado == null || resultado.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

but every time I run this I get this error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class java.lang.Long for parameter id_curso with expected type of class br.udesc.model.entidade.Curso from query string select u from Disciplina u where u.curso =:id_curso.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says you are trying to set `Curso` as `Long` when the query is expecting the entity.

Change your query string to: `u.curso.[cursoId] =` and it should work